# I am unable to find the issue with my code that checks if a given word is present in a matrix or not

Tags: c++, matrix, depth-first-search

```
bool dfs(vector<vector<char>>& A, vector<vector<bool>> &visit,string word,int i,int j,int l){
    
    if(l==word.length())
        return true;
    
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=A.size() || j>=A[0].size())
        return false;
    
    if(visit[i][j])
        return false;
    
    visit[i][j]=true;
    
    if(A[i][j]==word[l])
        return dfs(A,visit,word,i+1,j,l+1) || dfs(A,visit,word,i-1,j,l+1) || dfs(A,visit,word,i,j-1,l+1) || dfs(A,visit,word,i,j+1,l+1);
    
    return false;
    
}

class Solution {
public:
    bool exist(vector<vector<char>>& board, string word) {
        
        int r=board.size(),c=board[0].size();
        
        vector<vector<bool>> visit(r,vector<bool>(c,false));
        
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
                if(dfs(board,visit,word,i,j,0))
                    return true;
        
        return false;
        
    }
};
```

I have written a dfs algorithm to solve the question.This works for a few cases but,The code fails for the following testcase : [["a","b"]]"ba". Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You try the first letter and mark it as visited. You never remove the mark. This means you can never see that letter again. DFS doesn't really work this way.

Comment: Your question is very similar to a standard interview question for finding words in a matrix. Have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boggle-find-possible-words-board-characters/ for some insight on how to approach the problem.